# Remove Lenovo bloatware from Windows 10 image

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop

I just purchased a Lenovo laptop, and it comes with a bunch of stuff pre-bundled that I'd like to remove. I've tried all the reset options in Windows 10, but Lenovo must have a configuration file or recovery partition that I can't see, and is reinstalling all of their bloatware/crapware when Windows 10 reinstalls.

Is there some way to prevent Lenovo from reinstalling the bloatware on reset? Or is the only way to do a clean installation?

Comment: Download a Windows 10 .ISO and install Windows, or just remove the software you don't want

Comment: Yeah, was hoping there was a config file or something I could delete that would prevent all the bloatware from being reinstalled on reset.

Comment: https://www.pcdecrapifier.com/

Comment: download a clean win10 ISO from Microsoft and reinstall Windows: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench

Comment: Looks like that's the best option. I did that and it worked just fine. Still kind of a bummer, but at least it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [reset option allows you to use a custom images as source](https://www.winhelp.us/custom-recovery-image-in-windows-8.html). Here the custom Lenovo image with all the pre- installed apps is used. The best way to get rid of the crap is to download a [clean Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench) and reinstall Windows.